# How can I search OCR'd PDFs for terms by their relative nearness to one another?

Tags: pdf, ocr, search, text-search

Say I want to search a mathematics PDF for the terms "basis" and "transformation", but "basis transformation" or "transformation basis" aren't located anywhere.

I would like to find whether there are paragraphs, or groups of adjacent paragraphs that contain these terms, so for instance, I could search for "basis" and "transformation" and I could obtain the page where "the transformation F produces a change of basis" appears. What sort of software would allow me to search PDFs in this manner?

Comment: You should clarify exactly what you want. At the moment it doesn´t sound for me like you are searching for software, which would make the question off topic.

Comment: @convert Thank you for the comment, I have edited the post accordingly.